# get the fields that are at the start and end on the date in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hope you can help me. I need to get the rows that meet the condition that if ass_id is at the beginning (20200101) and at the end of the date (20200501):

**id**  **id_asig**      **date**

1    123     20200101

2    123     20200501

3    124     20200101

4    125     20200101

5    125     20200501

6    126     20200203

7    126     20200501

expected result:

id_asign 

  123
 
 125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t.id_asg
from t
where t.asig_date = '20200101' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id_asg = t.id_asg  and t2.asig_date = '20200501'
             );
```

If you want `id_asg` values where the smallest is 20200101 and the largest 20200501, then use aggregation:

```
select t.id_asg
from t
group by t.id_asg
having min(t.asig_date) = '20200101' and
       max(t.asig_date) = '20200501' ;
```